# xampp control panel Apache port is not opening

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have downloaded XAMPP control panel and installed it, but when I run the control panel it shows the error below. I have changed the port id and the PID, but the same error is reported despite that. I have also reinstalled XAMPP three times, but the issue persists.

```
      [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
      [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
      [Apache]  Problem detected!
      [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 1444!
      [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
      [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
      [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port.
```

Comment: Do you have Skype running?

Comment: I didn't ask because I wanted to contact you, but a known problem is that both skype and xampp use the same ports. So changing the used ports in either one and restarting could fix your problem

Comment: But how to change the port.i dnt know how to change it.can u plz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For change port skype, you can choose menu Tools > options then choose advanced > Connection [read it](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA148/which-ports-need-to-be-open-to-use-skype-for-windows-desktop) change port besides 80